# SQL Plus Query - Multiple Table Query

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

This is causing me more trouble then it should.

I have the following sample tables:

```
____________________       ____________      
|   Name|   Number |       | Number   |
|_______|__________|       |__________|
| Alice |     1    |       |    1     |
| Bob   |     2    |       |    1     |
|_______|__________|       |__________|
```

I want my result to be:

```
_____________________________________
| Name   |   Number  | Count(Number) |
|________|___________|_______________|
| Alice  |     1     |      2        |
| Bob    |     2     |      0        |
|________|___________|_______________|
```

I'm going back and forward but I'm sure this shouldn't be so tricky. I assume I'm missing something.

I've modified Gordon's answer:

```
 select name, number count(t2.number)
 from table1 t1, 
 table2 t2 
 where t1.number = t2.number (+)
 group by t1.number;
```

Comment: Why does Alice have a count of 2 and Bob has nothing?

Comment: Oops the table was drawn wrong. Updated now

Comment: Still does not make sense.  what are you trying to count the rows in the tables?

Comment: Alice is number 1. I'm trying to count how many times her number is in table 2. Bob is number 2. I'm trying to count how many times his number is in table 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need a join and aggregation.  However, the join needs to be a `left outer join` to keep all the rows:

```
select name, number, count(t2.number)
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.number = t2.number
group by t1.name, t1.number;
```

And, the `count()` is counting the non-NULL values in the second table, so you can get `0` when there is no match.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect your answer. Problem now is if a column is CLOB (Which one is) it doesn't allow that column to be grouped.